Validate Eclipse product file using Maven/Tycho
I'm working on an RCP application that uses a plugin based product file and I would like to know if it possible to validate the product file with the same function as in the PDE UI. In the product file editor it is the “validate…” icon in the tool bar. I would like to have the Tycho build to fail if the product does not validate. (Fail early principle). So far I haven't found any solutions, I know there is org.eclipse.tycho.extras/target-platform-validation-plugin specifically for the target platform validation but is there anything similar to validate a product file and have the Tycho build fail if there any missing plugins/dependencies in the product? Here's an example of my pom.xml file -
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-p2-director-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>materialize-products</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>materialize-products</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>archive-products</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>archive-products</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <products>
                        <product>
                            <id>com.gui.product</id>
                            <attachId>GUI</attachId>
                            <archiveFileName>com.gui.product-${project.version}-${buildqualifier}
                            </archiveFileName>
                        </product>
                    </products>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

I tried adding <phase>verify</phase> to materialize-products goal as per some suggestions I found but that didn't help either.
Is this something that can be achieved?

Probably more likely to be answered on github tycho discussions
